# WPF textbox default size is too big?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am new to WPF and have this very simple window:

```
<Window x:Class="xyz"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xyz"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="400" Width="550" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Closing="Window_Closing">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Margin="150,0,0,0">Values are saved upon closing this window</Label>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Width="150">User Id</Label>
            <TextBox Width="380" x:Name="txtUserId" Text="{Binding Path=UserId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Pretty vanilla...why is the textbox rendered too big (height) for the text?

[image]

Comment: You can set the height using `<TextBox Height="24"/>` like you set width. The default height, I believe, is 16 and the default font size is 11. The default values are not based on your font size.

Comment: @Sach Thanks, if I set Height to 20 it seems okay...is it by design that the default values do not match (font size vs textbox height)

Comment: Yes. The default values are just set to those numbers. The WPF design concept is that everything can be easily scaled, so you have a ton of options to adjust all that in your XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Set VerticalAlignment="Center" on the TextBox